# How to implement Template Method in Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, design-patterns, nio

I'd like to create two HttpServlets with some variation of template method (GOF). So I created abstract class extended from HttpServlet:

```
abstract public class AbstractServlet extends HttpServlet {

    abstract void doSomeAction();

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs){

        try {
            //here some logging, getting headers etc.
            System.out.println("Nothing really matters");

            //invoke concrete class
            doSomeAction();

            //write response
            rs.getOutputStream().write(new String("Simple response from class " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName()).getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And two concrete class:

```
public class A extends AbstractServlet {

    @Override
    void doSomeAction() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing something in A");
    }
}


public class B extends AbstractServlet {
    @Override
    void doSomeAction() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing something in B");
    }
}
```

After invoke (successfully) one of those services,  I can't get any response. After some debugging, it'seems like Tomcat has some problem with NIO channels and latch:

> 2016-01-31 19:13:52 Http11NioProtocol [DEBUG] Socket:
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment@6bc6f271:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@2072289:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57585]], Status
>   in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [**CLOSED**]
>
> 2016-01-31 19:13:52 LimitLatch [DEBUG] Counting
>   down[http-nio-8080-exec-2] **latch=1**

But to be honest, I don't know what's going on. The funny part is, when servlet consume all servletrequest input stream by for example IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream is), everything works fine!

```
abstract public class AbstractServlet extends HttpServlet {

    abstract void doSomeAction();

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs){

        try {
            //here some logging, getting headers etc.


        //Consume all inputStream
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(rq.getInputStream());

        //invoke concrete class
        doSomeAction();

        //write response
        rs.getOutputStream().write(new String("Simple response from class " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName()).getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Where is the problem?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem. I send big http post, with ~100 MB content, but I read only first 1024 B of message, because of business requirement (along with specification, i'm able to find interesting me information on the very beginning of the message). As I can see, Tomcat don't allow me to break out input stream after 1024B and send response immediatelly.

So, my final question is:

Is it possible to do something like that (read only part of the message)? Or is it against TCP standard?

Comment: What did you try? You should be able to close input stream. One more approach is to send 1024b meta info in headers

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to close input stream, but that is not solving my problem. It seems that I'm able to response into client ONLY when I read ENTIRE request message. Furthermore, It's not possible to send metadata in headers.